# pip3 point to a different place after conda initiate a new env

Tags: python, python-3.x, conda

On my Mac I created a new python env by

```
conda create --name myenv python=3.6.8
```

I want to confirm the versions, so I checked these:

```
conda activate myenv 

~ » which pip
/Users/chris/opt/anaconda3/envs/myenv/bin/pip

~ » which pip3                                              
/usr/local/bin/pip3

~ » which python                                            
/Users/chris/opt/anaconda3/envs/myenv/bin/python

~ » which python3                                          
/Users/chris/opt/anaconda3/envs/myenv/bin/python3
```

I'm a bit confused. Why does `pip3` point to a different place outside the env? Is it expected or need to be fixed?

Comment: Try checking your bin/pip and bin/activate scripts. In bin/pip, look if the shebang line is correct. Then on your bin/activate, check to see if your VIRTUAL_ENV is ok. In your case, pip3.

Comment: Note, Conda never uses the `pip3` or `pip2` aliases. It only ever installs `pip` as `pip` in each environment.

Comment: @vcruvinelr my anaconda3/bin/activate has 
#!/bin/sh
_CONDA_ROOT="/Users/yongtian.he/opt/anaconda3"
# Copyright (C) 2012 Anaconda, Inc
# SPDX-License-Identifier: BSD-3-Clause
\. "$_CONDA_ROOT/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" || return $?
conda activate "$@"

Comment: @vcruvinelr and which `bin/pip` do you refer to? the bin in `anaconda3` or `env/myenv`?

Comment: @merv so you are saying `pip3` pointing to something else is expected?

Comment: @Chris if you have Python installed elsewhere in your system and you have it on PATH, then yes. Also, that one should never use `pip3` if working with Conda. Generally, using pip at all with Conda is discouraged, but sometimes there's no alternative.